# python: print hex data instead of dictionary

Tags: python, zigbee, hexdump

Trying to decode Zigbee protocol from a Lowe's Iris SmartSwitch. The API callback I am using receives a frame that is already parsed, and sent to the callback as (I believe) a dictionary object (?).  My code:

```
def callback(data):
    print data
```

prints the following:

```
{'profile': '\xc2\x16', 'source_addr': '\x93\x0c', 'dest_endpoint':
 '\x02', 'rf_data': '\t\x00\x81\x00\x00', 'source_endpoint': '\x02',
 'options': '\x01', 'source_addr_long': '\x00\ro\x00\x03\xbc\xdf\xab',
'cluster': '\x00\xef', 'id': 'rx_explicit'}
```

I think this is in byte order, and I would much prefer an output like:

```
C2 16 93 0C 02 09 00 81 00 00 02 01 00 ...
```

Any way to do this with Python built-ins, with the given 'data' argument?  Also, I dont know how to interpret "\ro" as 8-bit hex. "\t", I assume, is 0x09.

What I would REALLY like is a raw dump of the dataframe, but I don't know if there is an API call for that.

Answer (score 2):

> Any way to do this with Python built-ins, with the given 'data' argument?

No. Dictionaries are arbitrarily ordered, so there's no way to know what order the values should be in.

> Also, I dont know how to interpret "\ro" as 8-bit hex.

It's "\r" and "o", which is 0x0d 0x6f.

> "\t", I assume, is 0x09.

```
>>> hex(ord('\t'))
'0x9'
```

> What I would REALLY like is a raw dump of the dataframe, but I don't know if there is an API call for that.

We don't know, since you haven't shared which API you're using in the first place.

Comment: +1 for a very complete answer.  You won't be able to get a raw dump of the data frame using that dictionary.  ZigBee protocol has the cluster ID and source and destination endpoints grouped together.  Check your API to see if there's another object you can reference as an array of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with no spaces, try the builtin `encode` method on the strings.

So `'\x0a\x0b\x0c'.encode('hex')` will yield `'0a0b0c'`.  There are a number of was you could iterate over dictionary values, but beware that it's an inherently un-ordered data structure.

Maybe something like this would do?

```
data = {'a':'\x0a\x0a\x0a', 'b':'\x0b\x0b\x0b'}
print '{' + ''.join( [ ('\'%s\'' %k) + ': \'%s\',' %data[k].encode('hex') for k in data ] ) + '}'
```

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
def printData(data)
    str = "> "
    for d in data:
        for e in data[d]:
            str = str + "{0:02X}".format(ord(e)) + " "
    print (str)
```

I use this string builder so I can use logging.info(str) instead of print...